# DIV stuck to the left of page

Tags: html, css

I have created a fixed menu to the left of the page, and now I am wanting to create a “content” area to the right by setting values of left and right CSS values, however the content won’t adjust accordingly.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp3j24ub/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url(_assets/bg_2.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 300%;
}
@font-face {
  src: url("_assets/Socialico.ttf");
  font-family: nav-social-1;
}
@font-face {
  src: url("_assets/Socialico Plus.ttf");
  font-family: nav-social-2;
}
@font-face {
  src: url("_assets/Century Gothic.ttf");
  font-family: nav-item;
}
/*-----------------MENU CLASSES-----------------*/
.menu-gap {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-menu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.logo {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.logo-item {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transition: background-image 0.25s;
}
.logo-item {
  content: url(_assets/logo_up.png);
}
.logo-item:hover {
  content: url(_assets/logo_over_2.png);
}
.nav-gap {
  width: 22%;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
.nav-menu {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 375px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.nav-item {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 1px #c8c8c8;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.35s;
  -o-transition: color 0.35s;
  transition: color 0.35s;
}
.nav-item {
  color: #555;
}
.nav-item:hover {
  color: #b9a069;
}
.soc-menu {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.soc-item {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}
.soc-item {
  content: url(_assets/instagram_up.png);
}
.soc-item:hover {
  content: url(_assets/instagram_over_2.png);
}
.copyright-menu {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.copyright-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #999;
  font-family: nav-item;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*-----------------MENU CLASSES-----------------*/

/*-----------------CONTENT CLASSES-----------------*/
.content-wrapper {
  left: 350px;
  right: 50px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
/*-----------------CONTENT CLASSES-----------------*/
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-menu">
  <div class="menu-gap">
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="http://www.stephanieengland.com/">
      <div class="logo-item"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-gap">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="nav-menu">
    <a href="http://www.stephanieengland.com/about-me">
      <div class="nav-item">About Me
        <div class="nav-gap"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.stephanieengland.com/costumes">
      <div class="nav-item">Costumes
        <div class="nav-gap"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.stephanieengland.com/personal-works">
      <div class="nav-item">Personal Works
        <div class="nav-gap"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.stephanieengland.com/professional-credits">
      <div class="nav-item">Professional Credits
        <div class="nav-gap"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.stephanieengland.com/contact">
      <div class="nav-item">Contact
        <div class="nav-gap"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-gap">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="soc-menu">
    <a href="instagram">
      <div class="soc-item"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-gap">
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="copyright-menu">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="copyright-item">
        <br />
        <br />Stephanie England
        <br />© Copyright 2016</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-gap">
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<!-----------------MENU END----------------->

<!-----------------CONTENT START----------------->
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-text">Contact Header Here Not Yet Set</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-----------------CONTENT END----------------->

<!-----------------FOOTER START----------------->
<div class="footer">
  <div class="soc-footer">
    <div class="soc-footer-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-----------------FOOTER END----------------->
```

Comment: You’re using `left` and `right` on `.content-wrapper` without using a non-static `position` (e.g. `position: absolute;`). Therefore, these properties won’t have any effect. Try adding `position: absolute;` to `.content-wrapper`. Is this what you want?

Comment: I have tried that and even that does not fix my problem :(

Comment: What is your expected result then?

Comment: I am aiming for the content div to be 50px off the right of the sidebar-menu div, and 50px off the right of the page. WIth that the width will be auto to adjust to whatever size screen may be used.

Comment: Strangely, `position: absolute;` works in the Stack Snippet, but not on JSFiddle.

Comment: Hmm...it doesnt seem to work on my saved HTML page either :(

Comment: Take a look, if that helps:

www.djscimmia.com/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the `.sidebar-menu` div a position of fixed takes it out of the flow of the document. So Your `.content=wrapper` div ignores it and positions itself flush to the left of the viewport. You can give it a margin-left of 250px:

```
.content-wrapper{
    margin-left:250px;  
}
```

To compensate for this, but if you just want your menu to stick to the left of the viewport, I would suggest floating it (and your content wrapper) instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/8rcws951/

Comment: I have tried that in my saved HTML page, viewed it on Chrome and it does not solve my issue. I will upload it to my server and link the page

Comment: Let me know when you do and I'll take a look.

Comment: www.djscimmia.com/test/

Comment: It works for me, in Chrome. Are you sure you're targeting `.content-wrapper`?

Comment: I just added a second ".content-wrapper" class to my CSS sheet and added the margin-left...it seemed to work. But why do I need TWO classes?

Comment: That's weird. Post the new link and I'll have another look.

Comment: It's your conditional comments borking the code (i.e. <!---these--->). CSS comments should be formatted /* like this */

Comment: Damn it! All that for some stupid commenting format problem lol Thanks heaps symlink!

Comment: No problem. It's always the little things.

Comment: Haha Ain't that the truth. Legend! Cheers :)